# USB Flash drive not showing as removable drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, removable-media

Yesterday I bought SanDisk Cruzer Blade 4 GB USB Flash drive. I connected it to my Windows 7 laptop there it is shown as local drive and not as a removable drive. I need it to be shown as a removable drive. I connected this drive to Windows XP desktop PC as well, but there also it is showing as local drive.

I want this drive to be shown as removable drive for one of my software to work. Please let me know how to make it removable.

Thanks and Regards,

Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be San disk has changed them to meet Windows 8 and forces the new san disk to appear as hdd no matter OS version.  Beside problem for your software makes unusable in sync in windows media player.